# Export PHP Chart to PDF

Tags: pdf, charts, flot

I'm looking for suggestions on exporting PHP Charts to PDF format. 
I am currently using Flot Chart. I have got all my charts working perfect I only need to exporting them to PDF. Any idea please?

Thank you,

Zina

Comment: On my last project, I did this on the server using phantomjs (http://phantomjs.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Flot Chart is a client side solution for charts, so you would need to use javascript PDF library such as jsPDF to export image to PDF; Or you can serialize image and post back to server side using base64 or other binary to text encoding methods, then you can process the image however you want once images are sent to server side. If you use PHP, you can use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/). Personally, I prefer the later.

[PHP Chart](http://phpchart.org) has code snippets demonstrates the later approach sending data to server side for process.

URL: [Export phpChart on the server side](https://phpchart.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/443666-how-to-export-my-chart-on-the-server-side-in-php).

Comment: Any examples please ?

Comment: this link: https://phpchart.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/443666-how-to-export-my-chart-on-the-server-side-in-php